# What do these regular expressions mean?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm venturing to read a code in Perl and found the following regular expressions:

```
$str =~ s/(<.+?>)|(&\w+;)/ /gis; 
$str =~ /(\w+)/gis
```

I wonder what these codes represent.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#op_=%7E ;)

Comment: m//i only affects case, it is a no-op when there are no letters in the regex. It should not be on either of the matches. m//s only affects the dot (.) metacharacter, it is a no-op when there is no dot in the reges. It should not be on the last match. In short, I distrust the programmer that wrote the code above as they seem to be throwing modifiers onto the end willy-nilly without understanding what they do.

Comment: A few people have told you that the first example removes all HTML/XML tags from text. That's not correct. It's a naive attempt to write a regex that removes all HTML/XML tags from text. It doesn't work though. Oh, it'll work in the vast majority of cases, but there will be corner cases that break it. It's actually a textbook example of why you shouldn't attempt to parse XML or HTML with a regex. Use a parsing module instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one `$str =~ s/(<.+?>)|(&\w+;)/ /gis;` does a sustitution:

```
$str      : the variable to work on
=~        : do the subs and save in the same variable
s         : substitution operator
 /        : begining or the regex
  (       : begining of captured group 1
   <      : <
   .+?    : one or more of any char NOT greedy
   >      : >
  )       : end of capture group 1
 |        : alternation
  (       : begining of captured group 2
   &      : &
   \w+    : one or more word char ie: [a-zA-Z0-9_]
   ;      : ;
  )       : end of group 2
 /        : end of search part
          : a space
 /        : end of replace part
 gis;     : global, case insensitive, multi-line
```

This will replace all tags and encoded element like `&amp;` or `&lt;` by a space.

The second one expect that it left at least one word.

Answer (score 4):

One way to help deciper regular expressions is to use the YAPE::Regex::Explain module from CPAN:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
#...may need to single quote $ARGV[0] for the shell...
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new( $ARGV[0] )->explain;
```

Assuming this snippet is named 'rexplain' you would do:

```
$ ./rexplain 's/(<.+?>)|(&\w+;)/ /gis'
```

Answer (score 4):

The first strips out every XML/HTML tag and every character entity, replacing each one with a space. The second finds every substring consisting entirely of word characters.

In detail:

The first part of the first expression first matches a `<`, then any character with the `.` (newlines included thanks to the `/s` flag at the end). The `+` modifier would match one or more characters up until the last `>` found in `$str`, but the `?` after it makes it not greedy, so it only matches up to the first `>` encountered. The second part matches `&` followed by any word character until `;` is found. Since `;` is not a word character, the `?` modifier is not needed. The `s/` up front means a substitution, and the bit after the second `/` means that's what any match is substituted with. The `/gis` at the end means *g*reedy, case *i*nsensitive, and *s*ingle line.

The second expression finds the first substring of non-word characters and puts it in `$1`. If you call it repeatedly, the `/g` at the end means that it will keep matching every instance in `$str`.

Answer (score 3):

The first one takes a string and replaces html tags or html character codes with a space

The second one makes sure there is still a word left when done.

Answer (score 1):

These "codes" are regular expressions. Type this to learn more:

```
perldoc perlre
```

The code above replaces with blanks some HTML/XML tags and some URL-encoded characters such as

```
 &nbsp;
```

from $str. But there are better ways to do this using CPAN modules. The code then tries to match and capture into variable $1 the first word in $str.
Ex:

```
perl -le '$str = "foo<br>&nbsp;bar<another\ntag>baz"; print $str; $str =~ s/(<.+?>)|(&\w+;)/ /gis; $str =~ /(\w+)/gis; print $str; print $1;'
```

It prints:

```
foo<br>&nbsp;bar<another
tag>baz
foo  bar baz
foo
```

Comment: May I request you to please [vote to undelete this question please](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65958971/548225)

Comment: @anubhava Sorry, but I found no option to vote to undelete. The only option available is the opposite: close the question... Maybe I lack the privilege/rep.

Comment: Oh not a problem and thanks for responding. May be that's right. There is an `undelete` link just below the question but I guess it may require certain reputation level to see that.