# sed : how remove selected number of white spaces (tabs) from beginning of each line

Tags: regex, sed

I have some python sample code with 6 white useless spaces in the  beginning of each line.

I have this code to remove all white spaces...

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//'
```

But how to remove just specified number of white spaces ( in my case 6) ?

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/^[[:blank:]]{6}//;s/[[:blank:]]+$//'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

This `sed` should work for you (based on your comments):

```sh
sed -E 's/^[[:blank:]]{19}//;s/[[:blank:]]+$//' file
```

To save changes inline:

```sh
sed -i.bak -E 's/^[[:blank:]]{19}//;s/[[:blank:]]+$//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner (for 19 whitespaces, per your comment):

```
perl -pe '^\s{19}' in_file > out_file
```

Or to change the file in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -pe '^\s{19}' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)